# Avoid Symbols in Google font

Tags: fonts, webfonts, google-webfonts

I added fonts from google fonts, but they appear in web page as symbols!
I tested in chrome,and FireFox

Example image:

[image]

Comment: You have to set your page encode to UTF-8

Comment: While @JeanCedron already solved your problem for you, next time you have a question, remember to *include some code*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set your page encode to **UTF-8**